# Hibernate table relations with no foreign keys but shared field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys

I am having problems with a couple of tables that I need to relate. These tables have no foreign keys but they share a common field. I am not allowed to manipulate these tables because of the ETL process. 
I have two entities: CostCenter and WellboreCompletion. They both share a field called costCenterNumber. I would like to do a query using the costCenterNumber so both entities are returned.

CostCenter.java

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement

@Table(name = "DIM1_COST_CENTER", schema = "BIDW.dbo")
public class CostCenter implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "DK_COST_CENTER")
@GeneratedValue(generator="seq_item", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq_item",sequenceName="DK_COST_CENTER", allocationSize=1)
@XmlAttribute
private Integer  id;


@Column(name = "COST_CENTER_NUMBER")
@XmlAttribute
private String costCenterNumber;


@OneToOne (mappedBy = "costCenterNumber", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="COST_CENTER_NUMBER")
@XmlAttribute
private WellboreCompletion wellboreCompletion;

public String getCostCenterNumber() {
    return costCenterNumber;
}

public void setCostCenterNumber(String costCenterNumber) {
    this.costCenterNumber = costCenterNumber;
}

    public WellboreCompletion getWellboreCompletion() {
    return wellboreCompletion;
}

public void setWellboreCompletion(WellboreCompletion wellboreCompletion) {
    this.wellboreCompletion = wellboreCompletion;
}

//..more fields and more getters and setters
```

WellboreCompletion.java

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "DIM1_WELLBORE_COMPLETION", schema = "BIDW.dbo")
public class WellboreCompletion implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name = "DK_WELLBORE_COMPLETION")
@GeneratedValue(generator="seq_item", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq_item",sequenceName="DK_COMPLETION_NAME", allocationSize=1)
@XmlAttribute
private Integer  id;

@OneToOne(targetEntity = CostCenter.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "COST_CENTER_NUMBER",referencedColumnName = "COST_CENTER_NUMBER")
private String costCenterNumber;



public String getCostCenterNumber() {
    return costCenterNumber;
}

public void setCostCenterNumber(String costCenterNumber) {
    this.costCenterNumber = costCenterNumber;
}

.
.
//more fields with getters and setters
```

Endpoint (REST):

```
 @GET
 @Path("/costcenter/{id}")
 public CostCenter getCostCenter(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    return wellSvc.getCostCenter(id);
 }
```

The method in my service:

```
@Override
public CostCenter getCostCenter(int id) {
    CostCenter cc = BIDWEntityManager.find(CostCenter.class, id);
    return  cc;
}
```

I know that this search is using the primary key (ID) instead of costCenterNumber but I figured this would be the first step.

Logs:

```
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Hibernate: 
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)     select
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         costcenter0_.DK_COST_CENTER as DK_COST_1_1_1_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         costcenter0_.COMPANY_LONG_NAME as COMPANY_2_1_1_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         costcenter0_.COST_CENTER_CATEGORY_LONG_NAME as COST_CEN3_1_1_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         costcenter0_.COST_CENTER_LONG_NAME as COST_CEN4_1_1_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         costcenter0_.COST_CENTER_NUMBER as COST_CEN5_1_1_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         costcenter0_.COUNTRY_LONG_NAME as COUNTRY_6_1_1_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         costcenter0_.DISTRICT_LONG_NAME as DISTRICT7_1_1_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         costcenter0_.HIER_FIELD_LONG_NAME as HIER_FIE8_1_1_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         costcenter0_.HIER_FIELD_CODE as HIER_FIE9_1_1_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         costcenter0_.JOINT_VENTURE_CODE as JOINT_V10_1_1_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         costcenter0_.JOINT_VENTURE_LONG_NAME as JOINT_V11_1_1_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         costcenter0_.OPERATOR_LONG_NAME as OPERATO12_1_1_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         costcenter0_.REGION_LONG_NAME as REGION_13_1_1_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         wellboreco1_.DK_WELLBORE_COMPLETION as DK_WELLB1_4_0_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         wellboreco1_.WB_API_NUMBER as WB_API_N2_4_0_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         wellboreco1_.TX_RRC_DISTRICT_ID as TX_RRC_D3_4_0_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         wellboreco1_.COMPLETION_DATE as COMPLETI4_4_0_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         wellboreco1_.COST_CENTER_NUMBER as COST_CE11_4_0_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         wellboreco1_.INITIAL_PRODUCTION_DATE as INITIAL_5_4_0_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         wellboreco1_.WB_SURVEY as WB_SURVE6_4_0_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         wellboreco1_.WB_GEOGRAPHIC_FOOTAGE as WB_GEOGR7_4_0_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         wellboreco1_.CLASS_LONG_NAME as CLASS_LO8_4_0_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         wellboreco1_.WELLBORE_NUMBER as WELLBORE9_4_0_,
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         wellboreco1_.STATUS_LONG_NAME as STATUS_10_4_0_ 
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)     from
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         BIDW.dbo.DIM1_COST_CENTER costcenter0_ 
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)     left outer join
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         BIDW.dbo.DIM1_WELLBORE_COMPLETION wellboreco1_ 
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)             on costcenter0_.DK_COST_CENTER=wellboreco1_.COST_CENTER_NUMBER 
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)     where
INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)         costcenter0_.DK_COST_CENTER=?
```

Errors:

```
11:36:04,687 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) could not load an entity: [com.dvn.search.landFiles.detail.entity.CostCenter#44462] [select costcenter0_.DK_COST_CENTER as DK_COST_1_1_1_, costcenter0_.COMPANY_LONG_NAME as COMPANY_2_1_1_, costcenter0_.COST_CENTER_CATEGORY_LONG_NAME as COST_CEN3_1_1_, costcenter0_.COST_CENTER_LONG_NAME as COST_CEN4_1_1_, costcenter0_.COST_CENTER_NUMBER as COST_CEN5_1_1_, costcenter0_.COUNTRY_LONG_NAME as COUNTRY_6_1_1_, costcenter0_.DISTRICT_LONG_NAME as DISTRICT7_1_1_, costcenter0_.HIER_FIELD_LONG_NAME as HIER_FIE8_1_1_, costcenter0_.HIER_FIELD_CODE as HIER_FIE9_1_1_, costcenter0_.JOINT_VENTURE_CODE as JOINT_V10_1_1_, costcenter0_.JOINT_VENTURE_LONG_NAME as JOINT_V11_1_1_, costcenter0_.OPERATOR_LONG_NAME as OPERATO12_1_1_, costcenter0_.REGION_LONG_NAME as REGION_13_1_1_, wellboreco1_.DK_WELLBORE_COMPLETION as DK_WELLB1_4_0_, wellboreco1_.WB_API_NUMBER as WB_API_N2_4_0_, wellboreco1_.TX_RRC_DISTRICT_ID as TX_RRC_D3_4_0_, wellboreco1_.COMPLETION_DATE as COMPLETI4_4_0_, wellboreco1_.COST_CENTER_NUMBER as COST_CE11_4_0_, wellboreco1_.INITIAL_PRODUCTION_DATE as INITIAL_5_4_0_, wellboreco1_.WB_SURVEY as WB_SURVE6_4_0_, wellboreco1_.WB_GEOGRAPHIC_FOOTAGE as WB_GEOGR7_4_0_, wellboreco1_.CLASS_LONG_NAME as CLASS_LO8_4_0_, wellboreco1_.WELLBORE_NUMBER as WELLBORE9_4_0_, wellboreco1_.STATUS_LONG_NAME as STATUS_10_4_0_ from BIDW.dbo.DIM1_COST_CENTER costcenter0_ left outer join BIDW.dbo.DIM1_WELLBORE_COMPLETION wellboreco1_ on costcenter0_.DK_COST_CENTER=wellboreco1_.COST_CENTER_NUMBER where costcenter0_.DK_COST_CENTER=?]: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'N/A' to data type int.
.
.
WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) SQL Error: 245, SQLState: S0001
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'N/A' to data type int.
INFO  [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity: [com.dvn.search.landFiles.detail.entity.CostCenter#44462]
DEBUG [org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Mark transaction for rollback
TRACE [org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Setting cache mode to: NORMAL
TRACE [org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Closing session
TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@7f22462b]
TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Closing logical connection
TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Logical connection closed
TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) JTA sync : afterCompletion(4)
TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Transaction afterCompletion callback [status=4]
TRACE [org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Session was closed; nothing to do
TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) after transaction completion
DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Aggressively releasing JDBC connection
TRACE [org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) after transaction completion
ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component WellServiceImpl for method public abstract com.dvn.search.landFiles.detail.entity.CostCenter com.dvn.search.service.WellService.getCostCenter(int): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity: [com.dvn.search.landFiles.detail.entity.CostCenter#44462]
```

The root cause seems to be this:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'N/A' to data type int.
```

Not sure why this conversion is happening since I have no int data types. 'N/A' is the value of costCenterNumber for the case I was testing but it is declared as a String in the entity and a VARCHAR in the table.

DDL:

DIM1_COST_CENTER:

```
COST_CENTER_NUMBER VARCHAR(30)
```

DIM1_WELLBORE_COMPLETION:

```
COST_CENTER_NUMBER VARCHAR(30),
```

Answer (score 0):

That sql join is comparing these two values:

```
left outer join BIDW.dbo.DIM1_WELLBORE_COMPLETION wellboreco1_ 
 on costcenter0_.DK_COST_CENTER=wellboreco1_.COST_CENTER_NUMBER
```

DK_COST_CENTER is the Integer ID member of the CostCenter object.
COST_CENTER_NUMBER is a String member of the Wellbore object.

Comment: thanks for your response. What would be the correct annotation to compare two field where none of them are either PK or FK?

Answer (score 0):

Your COST_CENTER_NUMBER is defined as VARCHAR but your class CostCenter class has its id as Int so you are getting the exception.

Change the ID type to String and it should work.

The problem has nothing to do with the lack of primary keys.

Comment: thanks for your response. What would be the correct annotation to compare two field where none of them are either PK or FK?